# Python Pandas: Using ffill based on condition of other column where it's blank

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I tried group by then ffill and nothing has worked. :(

How do I use ffill based on a blank column called "Rec". So if this column is blank, then fill the previous value on the "Rec" column and then replace "Loc1" and Loc with previous value as well?

Here is my df:

```
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+
| Lot    | Rec      | Part                       | Loc1    | Loc        |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+
| Y19105 | BIPA6.02 | PHEMT6_BGATE_70NM_EBEAM.05 | B_EBEAM | B_F_EBEAM  |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+
| Y19105 |          | PHEMT6_BGATE_70NM_EBEAM.05 | B_PC    | B_PC_STOCK |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+
| Y19105 | BIPA6.02 | PHEMT6_BGATE_70NM_EBEAM.05 | B_EBEAM | B_F_EBEAM  |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+
| Y19105 | BIPA6.02 | PHEMT6_BGATE_70NM_EBEAM.05 | B_EBEAM | B_F_EBEAM  |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+
| Y19105 | BIPA6.02 | PHEMT6_BGATE_70NM_EBEAM.05 | B_EBEAM | B_F_EBEAM  |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+
| Y19105 | BIPA6.02 | PHEMT6_BGATE_70NM_EBEAM.05 | B_EBEAM | B_F_EBEAM  |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+
| Y19105 |          | PHEMT6_BGATE_70NM_EBEAM.05 | B_PC    | B_PC_STOCK |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+
| Y19105 |          | PHEMT6_BGATE_70NM_EBEAM.05 | B_PC    | B_PC_STOCK |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+
| Y19105 |          | PHEMT6_BGATE_70NM_EBEAM.05 | B_PC    | B_PC_STOCK |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+
```

The output I want:

```
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+-----------+
| Lot    | Rec      | Part                       | Loc1    | Loc       |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+-----------+
| Y19105 | BIPA6.02 | PHEMT6_BGATE_70NM_EBEAM.05 | B_EBEAM | B_F_EBEAM |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+-----------+
| Y19105 | BIPA6.02 | PHEMT6_BGATE_70NM_EBEAM.05 | B_EBEAM | B_F_EBEAM |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+-----------+
| Y19105 | BIPA6.02 | PHEMT6_BGATE_70NM_EBEAM.05 | B_EBEAM | B_F_EBEAM |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+-----------+
| Y19105 | BIPA6.02 | PHEMT6_BGATE_70NM_EBEAM.05 | B_EBEAM | B_F_EBEAM |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+-----------+
| Y19105 | BIPA6.02 | PHEMT6_BGATE_70NM_EBEAM.05 | B_EBEAM | B_F_EBEAM |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+-----------+
| Y19105 | BIPA6.02 | PHEMT6_BGATE_70NM_EBEAM.05 | B_EBEAM | B_F_EBEAM |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+-----------+
| Y19105 | BIPA6.02 | PHEMT6_BGATE_70NM_EBEAM.05 | B_EBEAM | B_F_EBEAM |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+-----------+
| Y19105 | BIPA6.02 | PHEMT6_BGATE_70NM_EBEAM.05 | B_EBEAM | B_F_EBEAM |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+-----------+
| Y19105 | BIPA6.02 | PHEMT6_BGATE_70NM_EBEAM.05 | B_EBEAM | B_F_EBEAM |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------+-----------+
```

Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Are the blank values `NaN` or a string

Comment: I tried this and it won't work because "Loc1" and "Loc" is not blank. I want to replace its currently value with previous value if "Rec" is blank. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Got it, check the answers from me and Anurag Dabas below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you could try changing the `Loc1` and `Loc` values to `NaN` if the `Rec` column is `NaN`, and then use `ffill` on the whole DataFrame.

Try this:

```
df.loc[df['Rec'].isnull(), ['Loc1', 'Loc']] = np.nan
df.ffill()
```